# Limiting minimal scale to 1 still goes to negative values

Tags: objects, constraints, scale

So if I limit objects scale (by a constraint) to minimum of 1 and maximum of 2 and start scaling it, it still manages to go over on inverting it self to negative values keeping the limits to -1 and -2.
Checking "For Transform" does not help.

Comment: I tested this, and confirmed the issue in 2.82a. It seems really sad that this doesn't work as one would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known essue, and now it has "To Do" status:

https://developer.blender.org/T37623

And this is one of two unsolved problems from 2018 TO DO animation list:

https://developer.blender.org/T55365

It's sounds easy, until you try to make it work on matrix transformations.